# NHibernate SysCache storage

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, nhibernate, caching, fluent-nhibernate

I am using Nhibernet with SysCache Provider for second level cache in an Asp.net MVC 4 application. Somewhere i found that SysCache use ASP.Net default cache system to store the cache items. To reduce the use of my limited RAM, i have implemented my custom cache provider which store data in MongoDB.

Now my question is, as i am using my custom cache provider using mongodb, where will be the nhibernet second level cache data stored? Is in mongodb by my custom cache provider or it still will be in RAM?

By the way, my ultimate target is, i want the NHibernet second level cache using SysCache or any other free cache provider but not want to store the cache items in RAM rather in mongodb. Please give a better suggestion to achieve it.

regard

Habib

Answer (score 1):

> Now my question is, as i am using my custom cache provider using mongodb, where will be the nhibernet second level cache data stored?

As you have already developed mongo's SLC and if you change settings the data will be probably in mongo ... ?

**The point of caching is to provide faster way how to obtain/fetch frequent data than `select` them from original database.**

Your approach makes perfect sense to work correctly with limited memory but I'm not sure whether it will improve the performance of your application how the point of SLC would require.

You store cached data as document/blob in mongo? Have you compare performance against original cache and w/o cache?

If your solution would be successful it requires to develop mongo's cache better than your original queries against RDBMS. This does not have to be true by default. Depends on your purpose and queries you use.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the answer. By the way, i have implemented custom cache provider for Asp.Net to store my site cache data in MongoDb, not Nhibernet Second Level Cache Provider. But i am interested to know, as Nhibernet SysCache 2 Provider use Asp.net Cache system to cache the nhibernet data, will it store the data in my mongodb as my site store the cache data in mongodb?

Comment: Actually, I am not sure about the performance. but some people suggest to store cache and session state data in NoSql type database like mongodb to get better performance rather store in expensive RDBMS database like sqlserver. I know InProc is best option for best performance, but RAM memory is expensive to me. On the other hand, it may help in webfarm based hosting from lossing cache or sessionstate data on server instance change. Please correct me if i am wrong or suggest me a better solution if you have.

Comment: I'm not able to respond to your first question but IMHO yes :-) The question regarding SQL vs. NoSQL depends on structure of your data and purpose of your queries. SQL uses relation decomposition and once you want to perform queries like `SELECT something FROM ... JOIN ...` etc. the best way is to use RDBMS like MySQL. On the other hand when you want to store one document, e.g. JSON, the best option is to use Mongo as it supports simple quering into particular document. But I have to say that you can perfectly use MySQL to store blob data. I've made some performance tests and the numbers

Comment: were almost same. Also depends on transaction requirements. Scalability seems important for you but twitter/facebook still use MySQL in cluster so it also make perfect sense to use. As I've say at the beginning, the structure and quering is the first point how to solve your problem.